# NoClassDeffound could not initialize hibernatesessionfactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jar, issue-tracking

Below see the exception trace:

FathomScheduler contains this HibernateSessionFactory class file.

It compiles without any errors and I am running it in exploded archive. I am not sure if its enough to have the hibernate jars in the Eclipse build path or do we have to copy the hibernate jar files into the lib directory under deploy directory of Jboss. I am new to Java.

```
09:54:36,040 ERROR [[/FathomScheduler]] StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datumsoftware.fathom.fathomcommon.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory
    at com.datumsoftware.fathom.fathomejb.interceptor.FathomInterceptor.intercept(FathomInterceptor.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.java:59)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:73)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_31433872.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_31433872.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_31433872.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_31433872.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInNoTx(TxPolicy.java:66)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.TxInterceptor$NotSupported.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:176)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:216)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:207)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:164)
    at $Proxy336.fetchAutoDiscoverableHardwares(Unknown Source)
    at com.datumsoftware.fathom.fathomscheduler.servlet.AutoDiscoveryAgent.init(AutoDiscoveryAgent.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)

09:54:36,078 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/FathomWeb
09:54:36,167 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
09:54:36,182 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
09:54:36,187 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221634)] Started in 4m:25s:25ms

Since this error seems prevail all over the internet forums and is not easy to interpret. I have tried understanding `NoClassDefFoundError` - exception during compile time but not during run time. I tried putting jars in the class path but I can't avoid this error. Need help.
```

**I am using :** 
 - jboss 5.1.0 
 - myeclipse 8.6
 - postgres 9.2.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

please be sure that you have all the corresponding jars in the right place.
This are the jars i use for hibernate:

- hibernate
- dom4j
- commons
- antlr

The exception is telling you are missing commons jar.
Also, all jars must be placed in "WEB-INF/lib" in order to be found.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the following jars antlr-2.7.6.jar
hibernate3.jar, commons-collections-2.1.1.jar, commons-logging-1.0.4.jar in the lib folder under project.ear folder. I guess that what you meant. I am still getting that error. It maps the hibernate files in the trace logs after that it give me NoClassDefFound error. It is so cryptic i can't find where is it causing the fault. Thanks

Comment: are you sure that these .jars are located in the WEB-INF/lib where the project is running? In my case i use tomcat then to be sure of this I browse ProjectFolder/WEB-INF/lib and look for the jars

Comment: I have faced the same error before and i fixed it by adding the jars to whe WEB-INF/lib folder, or the other way if you use Eclipse is by adding manually the jar via right click in the project->java build path-> and in the tab Libraries select Add Jars and then browse it...

Comment: Also, look at this post it may help you...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318071/jar-file-location-ear-file-or-server-lib-folder/12318669#12318669